# Created LinkButton using C# code not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have created link button using c# code but these are not click able why?
This is c# code

```
<% {
       List<string> PMlist = new List<string>();
       PMlist = PManifacutrerList;
       foreach (string PM in PMlist)
       {
           Response.Write(PM);
       }
   }
%>
```

And following code is used to add list li in the PMlist

```
PMList.Add(
    "<li><asp:LinkButton ID=\"LinkButton1\" style=\"color: Blue;font-family: Microsoft New Tai Lue; text-decoration: none;\"  runat=\"server\">" + 
     ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PM_name"].ToString() + "</asp:LinkButton></li>");
```

Comment: I've never tried that, but I'm pretty sure that simply writing a string with server control definitions to the reponse output will not work. You have to instantiate the controls.

Answer (score 1):

Your Response.Write(PM) is simply writing HTML to the response output. If you really want to use a LinkButton, you need to create an instance:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.Text = "click me";            
lb.Click += new EventHandler(delegate (object s, EventArgs ev) {
     // handle click event
});
form1.Controls.Add(lb);
```

If you don't need a server post back, then you can just use a simple link such as:

```
PMList.Add(
"<li><a href='#' style='color: Blue;font-family: Microsoft New Tai Lue; text-decoration: none;'>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PM_name"].ToString() + "</a></li>");
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write OnClick event

Comment: you are right but that is last option but not first as per my experience i am doing some thing wrong in my code but not getting it.

Comment: you are right actually i tried using your exampla and placing directly they are evaluat4ed differently

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to dynamically add a control there must be a container.
2. If you don't have a container on page you can a `placeholder`
   control & add controls to it
3. You must create an instance of control to add it onto page

   ```
   Label myLabel = new Label();
   myLabel.Text = "Sample Label";
   myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myLabel);
   ```

   [Adding Controls dynamically:MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx)